# Does access specifier matters for a friend function?

Tags: c++, friend

In a class, if the function is declared as friend within the different specifier like - private, protected, or public, then is there any difference. As per my understanding, friend function is not a member. Thus, it shouldn't matter. But, if I see static - it is also not a member, but access specifier matters a lot. So, I am a bit confused. How all these code works fine? Is there any difference among the following classes?

```
/** Private friend function **/

class frienddemoFunction
{
  private:
      unsigned int m_fanSpeed;
      unsigned int m_dutyCycle;
      /** This function is not a member of class frienddemo **/
      friend void printValues(frienddemoFunction &d);

  public:
      void setFanSpeed(unsigned int fanSpeed);
      unsigned int getFanSpeed();

};


/** Protected -- Friend Function **/
class frienddemoFunction
{
  private:
      unsigned int m_fanSpeed;
      unsigned int m_dutyCycle;

  public:
      void setFanSpeed(unsigned int fanSpeed);
      unsigned int getFanSpeed();

 protected:

 /** This function is not a member of class frienddemo **/
      friend void printValues(frienddemoFunction &d);


};

class frienddemoFunction
{
  private:
      unsigned int m_fanSpeed;
      unsigned int m_dutyCycle;

  public:
      void setFanSpeed(unsigned int fanSpeed);
      unsigned int getFanSpeed();

 /** This function is not a member of class frienddemo **/
      friend void printValues(frienddemoFunction &d);


};


 /** This function is not a member of class frienddemo **/
  friend void printValues(frienddemoFunction &d);
```

Comment: *"But, if I see static - it is also not a member"* -- Yes. It is.

Comment: Static is a class member and not an object member.

Comment: The term "object member" does not exist in the C++ standard. There are static class members and non-static class members.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter.

C++ standard, section § 11.3 / 9 [friend.class]

> The meaning of the friend declaration is the same whether the friend
>   declaration appears in the private, protected or public (9.2) portion
>   of the class member-specification.

**Note:**

A static function declared within the class is still a class member. A friend function is not.

Comment: Why static matters then?

Comment: @dexterous_stranger : A friend function is not a member function. `static` is a modifier for a class member. A friendship declaration dos not declare a member, it merely grants special access rights to a non-member (of the current class) function.